# In Javafx, how bind ObjectProperty<TimeStamp> with a textfield

Tags: javafx

For the bindings setting, how can I convert the `ObjectProperty<TimeStamp>` to `String`, is the following correct?

```
Bindings.bindBidirectional(admissionTextField.textProperty(), patient.admissionDateProperty(), new FormatStringConverter());
```

Comment: No, obviously not: [`FormatStringConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/converter/FormatStringConverter.html) does not provide a 0-agrument constructor.

Comment: how could i do it?

Comment: It would probably be easiest to implement & use a `StringConverter<Timestamp>`. Note however that this converter will receive partial inputs from the `TextField`. It may be best to only do the conversion, if the user focuses another node or presses enter/return...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind a Timestamp to any JavaFX control without writing a bit of custom code. In this case only the date is required and not the time. Therefore you can use a DatePicker and bind that to a ObjectProperty property in your bean. Add a getter and setter for a Timestamp in the bean and have these methods get and set out of the property. You can see an example of how this is done in a project that I wrote at https://gitlab.com/omniprof/timestamp_demo

PS: This question is from a student of mine doing an assigment that required a Timestamp on a JavaFX form. I figured it maight be a problem others face.

Comment: Thanks Prof Ken, this really helps me!!

Comment: why a DatePicker (vs. a TextField with TextFormatter)? Yeah, I'm aware of special constraints in teaching <g>

Comment: Simple reason, users cannot be trusted. Is it yy-mm-dd or mm-dd-yy. Is it yy or yyyy. It’s not about teaching, it’s about using the right control for the job and for dates it’s always the DatePicker.